Mouse Scrolling "deadzone" in Ubuntu, Debian
Apologies if this is a redundant post - I haven't found one specific name for the issue, nor one post describing the same triggers to the problem or solutions that work on my end.
Symptoms: any mouse connected to the laptop will have a "deadzone"/null zone in scrolling whereas scrolling up and down by one click repeatedly won't do anything - e.g. in order to reverse my scrolling direction, I'll have to click the wheel twice in order to scroll once in the opposite direction. When scrolling continuously in any direction (after escaping the deadzone), each scroll notch corresponds correctly to one movement; the issue is purely when switching directions.
This behavior seems to only ever happen in Firefox and Minecraft. I have yet to find other problematic programs.
Hardware:
The laptop is an Asus Zenbook 14 (UX3402ZA) dual booted, Windows 10 and Ubuntu, though I've had the same issue with Debian 12. The mouse I'm troubleshooting with is a Corsair Katar Wireless (paired via bluetooth), though the issue seems to behave exactly the same with other bluetooth, 2.4GHz, and wired mice.
Triggers:
As far as I can tell with bluetooth; once I pair the mouse successfully, all behavior is as expected until the touchpad is used to scroll. From that point, the above symptoms begin. A reboot and repairing of the mouse seems to revert behavior to normal (until the touchpad scrolls). Oddly, I could not replicate this behavior when booted to the Ubuntu live ISO which I had used for installation. When running Windows 10, the problem doesn't exist.
My Troubleshooting:
I've asked/searched around to no success, but I've read a few things;

The computer may not have enough resources or wiggle room to allocate (almost the same words I read - I didn't really understand this one)
According to this post, a user started experiencing this problem after upgrading to kernel 6.1. I subsequently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 with kernel 5.15.0-43, in which the behavior remains unresolved.
Previously, when I had Debian 12 installed, I ran evtest while triggering the behavior - both before and and after, the mouse scroll appeared to be detected the exact same, whereas one click, regardless of "direction," showed one positive or negative reaction (for lack of better terminology) - like the normal behavior I would expect in Firefox/Minecraft.

Below is an evtest clip from scrolling the mouse down/up/down/up, while the behavior was present;
Event: time 1722654009.094229, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1722654009.701843, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value -1
Event: time 1722654009.701843, type 2 (EV_REL), code 11 (REL_WHEEL_HI_RES), value -120
Event: time 1722654009.701843, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1722654010.519376, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 1
Event: time 1722654010.519376, type 2 (EV_REL), code 11 (REL_WHEEL_HI_RES), value 120
Event: time 1722654010.519376, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1722654011.299353, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value -1
Event: time 1722654011.299353, type 2 (EV_REL), code 11 (REL_WHEEL_HI_RES), value -120
Event: time 1722654011.299353, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1722654012.102271, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 1
Event: time 1722654012.102271, type 2 (EV_REL), code 11 (REL_WHEEL_HI_RES), value 120

As mentioned in the linked reddit post, there seems to be both high resolution and "normal" inputs being registered. My guess would be that using only the "normal" inputs would solve the problem, but I'm still a linux beginner and wouldn't want to start an XY problem lol.
While I currently have Ubuntu installed, I'm also having this issue in Debian 12 (and possibly some other distros as well?) so I wouldn't mind having the issue resolved in either OS. Again, note that the issue was somehow not present in the live ISO before installation.
Update 1: when using Xorg [X11?], the issue doesn't seem to exist (although I also realized that gestures only work in Wayland). I'll be troubleshooting the issue in Wayland.
Update 2: firefox decided to update itself and it's no longer affected by the bug (while Minecraft is still affected). Smooth ["pixel-perfect"?] touchpad scrolling is also working in Firefox (as opposed to 3 lines at a time), which I think is new behavior. So maybe the problem is that Minecraft just doesn't properly recognize/handle high resolution scroll events?

A well-written first question from a new contributor. I wish all contributors write their posts at least that well. Welcome to Unix & Linux SE.

@KamilMaciorowski Thank you - I've done my fair share of forum-troubleshooting from the helping side, so I should know how to make my question easy for the helpers haha
